# Nested function repeat

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function REPEAT, instead of for. Here is my code :

```
function REPETER(nb) {
return {
    INSTRUCTIONS: function(callback) {
        for(i_repeter=1;i_repeter<=nb;i_repeter++) callback();
        return this ;
    }
};
}
var x = 1 ;
REPETER(5)
.INSTRUCTIONS (() => {
xxx = xxx + 2 ;
alert(i_repeter);
}
);
```

It works well.

But :

```
REPETER(2)
.INSTRUCTIONS(() => {
xxx = xxx + 1 ;
REPETER(5)
.INSTRUCTIONS(() => {
xxx = xxx + 2 ;
alert(i_repeter);
}
);
}
);
```

doesn't work, the first REPETER does nothing.

How can i fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `i_repeter` within the `INSTRUCTIONS` function. Because you're not declaring it, you're creating an *implicit global*. Globals are a Bad Thing, implicit ones doubly so. Since you have a repeater calling a repeater, you end up with crosstalk; the first one thinks it's done before it is.

So:

```
function REPETER(nb) {
  return {
    INSTRUCTIONS: function(callback) {
      var i_repeter;                   // <=== Change is here
      for (i_repeter = 1; i_repeter <= nb; i_repeter++) callback();
      return this;
    }
  };
}
```

Also don't try to use `i_repeter` in your function updating `xxx` (and be sure to declare `xxx`).

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was a problem with the variable i_repeter, but I did'nt know exactly what it was.

The instruction alert(i_repeter) was a try to see where the problem was, it is not in my code, me apologies.