# Nested for loop only executes the outer loop once Javascript

Tags: javascript

so I was writing a bit of code to solve one of Project Euler's problems about palindromes:

```
var isPalindrome = function(num){
    var tempString = "";
    for(i = String(num).length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        tempString += String(num)[i];
    }
    if(tempString === String(num)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
};

var palindromes = [];
var inCount = 0;
var count = 0;
for(var i = 999; i > 99; i--){
    inCount++;
    for(var j = i; j > 99; j--){
        count++;
        if(isPalindrome(i*j)){
            palindromes.push(i*j);
        }
    }
}
console.log(inCount);
console.log(count);
console.log(Math.max(palindromes));
```

After some testing I discovered that the code is only running the outer for loop a single time. This appears to be because I call the isPalindrome function within the nested loop. When I remove the if(isPalindrome()) line the nested for loop executes as it should. I'm relatively new to Javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `isPalindrome` function is accessing the same iteration variable as your outer loop: `for(i = String(num).length - 1;`

Comment: I **just** answered this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410598/nested-function-repeat

Comment: General advice. Don't do `if (booleanCondition) return true; else return false;`. That's useless. Just `return booleanCondition;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you never declare `i` in `isPalindrome`, it's using the global `i` declared by the later code (odd as that may seem). Be sure to declare your variable *within* the function.

Comment: indeed, you are reassigning the i variable inside that function